# CUDA code doesnt work, why?

Tags: cuda, atomic

I have this code, but sometimes It works, sometimes NOT(write printf("ERR:%d\n", id)).
I work under CUDA 4.1 and have GTS450 which is compute capability 2.1.

The code doesnt have higher purpose, Iam just trying to find why Its not working, because My mind tell me, that right :]

If you want to run it, maybe you need to execute few times, when "error" appear or change grid size!

PS: [here you can download exe file for win64 - you need to have cuda4.1 driver](http://www.2shared.com/file/9UGyZuTm/cuda41_win64.html)

```
class MAN
{
public:
    int m_id;
    int m_use;

    __device__
    MAN()
    {
        m_id = -1;
        m_use = 0;
    }
};

__device__ int* d_ids = NULL;
__device__ int d_last_ids = 0;

__device__ MAN* d_mans = NULL;


__global__ void init()
{
    d_mans = new MAN[500];  //note: 500 is more than enough!
    d_ids = new int[500];

    for(int i=0; i < 500; i++)
        d_ids[i] = 0;
}


__device__ int getMAN() //every block get unique number, so at one moment all running blocks has different id
{
    while(true)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < 500; i++)
            if(atomicCAS(&(d_mans[i].m_use), 0, 1)==0)
                return i;
    }
}
__device__ void returnMAN(int id)
{
    int s = atomicExch(&(d_mans[id].m_use), 0);
}



__global__ void testIt()
{
    if(threadIdx.x==0)
    {
        int man = getMAN();

        int id = d_mans[man].m_id;
        if(id == -1)    //If It never works with this "id", its creating new
        {
            id = atomicAdd(&d_last_ids, 2);

            d_ids[id] = 10; //set to non-zero
            d_mans[man].m_id = id;  //save new id for next time

            printf("ADD:%d\n", id);
        }

        if(d_ids[id]==0)
            printf("ERR:%d\n", id); //THIS SHOULD NEVER HAPPEN, BUT BECOMES !!!

        returnMAN(man);
    }
}



int main()
{
    init<<<1, 1>>>();
    printf("init() err: %d\n", cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    testIt<<<20000, 512>>>();
    printf("testIt() err: %d\n", cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the `init` kernel call is failing? What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: No Its without cuda errors. Problem is that program jump on "printf("ERR:%d\n", id);" line, but This could never happen!

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve?  (At a higher level)

Comment: like I have writen: "The code doesnt have higher purpose, Iam just trying to find why Its not working,".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed this:

```
__device__ int* d_ids = NULL;
```

to this:

```
__device__ volatile int* d_ids = NULL;
```

and it works ok!!!

And even It doesnt need __threadfence();

Answer (score 1):

This seems to happen, because 
this code

```
    int id = d_mans[man].m_id;
    if(id == -1)    //If It never works with this "id", its creating new
    {
        id = atomicAdd(&d_last_ids, 2);

        d_ids[id] = 10; //set to non-zero
        d_mans[man].m_id = id;  //save new id for next time

        printf("ADD:%d\n", id);
    }

    if(d_ids[id]==0)
        printf("ERR:%d\n", id); //THIS SHOULD NEVER HAPPEN, BUT BECOMES !!!
```

Contains race condition if some block wrote to d_mans[man].m_id, but still haven't wrote to d_ids[id]. Probably compiler exchanges instruction "set to non-zero" and "save new id for next time" or cache just don't get updated in-time.

Actually, problem is with your allocator -- it is better to remember index of last used 'man' than look for it.

Comment: I think that problem is that variables are in cache, so they dont update it in-time. Because some "blocks" write errors, but after some time errors dont appear(cache update global memory). But question is how I can solve this?

Comment: Maybe solution: I can change code in getMAN(), so If I find some "free" man, I can check it if ids doesnt include non-zero value

Comment: I have tried my solution and it works without error, but still I dont get it why the cache doesnt update global memory immediately when block has done. Why It delayed??